# ODE with product of functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the real solution $x(t)$ of the following ODE

$$\dot{x}\ddot{x}+a\  \dddot{x} \dot{x} +b=0$$

with $a,b$  $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. I don't really know how to proceed though and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let $y := \dot{x}$. Then your equation simplifies to a second-order ODE, $y(\dot{y}+a  \ddot{y} ) +b=0$. Still non-linear though so that's not so easy to work with.

Comment: @Joe You can use a change of variables, letting $\dot{y}=f(y),$ so that $\ddot{y}=f'(y)\dot{y},$ hence $y(f(y)+af'(y)f(y))+b=0,$ which is equivalent to $yf\cdot(1+af')=-b,$ which is equivalent to $af'=\frac{-b}{yf}-1.$ This should be doable.

Comment: @Angel, nice method. Then you solve for $f$ to find the first order equation $\dot{y}=f(y)$, which you solve for $y(x)$. I didn't think about doing this before

Comment: @Joe Right, that is exactly the idea. It looks very tedious, but each individual step is pretty straightforward in concept.